# How I can customize the Leemon CMS to filter the content by customzied field?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, lemoon

I'm using Lemoon CMS. I've created a new Content Type, and i've modified it with new fields and all its working fine.

I created a new user control to show some data from my content type which the field ("isFeatured=true")

How I can customize the code to filter the content, and how i can sort the data by custom added field?

```
 ContentQuery query = new ContentQuery();
    query.ParentID = 70;
    query.MinDepth = 1;
    query.MaxDepth = 1;
    query.LanguageMode = LanguageMode.Fallback;
    query.SearchNonSearchable = null;
    query.ContentTypes.Add(typeof(Mindroute.Lemoon.Generated.ContentType.ServiceItem).FullName);

    query.ContentTypeMode = ContentTypeMode.Inherit;
    //query.OrderBy.Add(new SortItem(ContentColumn.Columns[6], "desc"));
    Response.Write(ContentColumn.Columns[6]);
    query.PageSize = 8;
    Entries = ContentService.Search(query).Cast<Mindroute.Lemoon.Generated.ContentType.ServiceItem>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you can simplify your code that gets the ServiceItems. You could simply use `ContentService.GetChildren<ServiceItem>(70)` instead of setting up a `ContentQuery`.

To filter and order by a specific property you could then use Linq like this:

```
var children = ContentService.GetChildren<ServiceItem>(70);
var filtered = children.Where(x => x.IsFeatured == true);
var ordered = filtered.OrderBy(x => x.SomeOtherProperty);
```

It is also possible to use ContentQuery to find items with custom properties, you would then need to set `ContentQuery.PropertyValue = new PersistedValue("IsFeatured", true);`

Comment: How i can order my content using a content type field using "ContentQuery"?

Comment: The "ContentService" gives me the following error: At least one object must implement IComparable!!  Please advise

Comment: I don't think you can use ContentQuery to order by a "custom" property. You need to use the OrderBy(x => x.Property) extension method for this.

Comment: but it gave me the following error:At least one object must implement IComparable

Comment: Hmm, never seen that before. Can you show some code?

Comment: var children = ContentService.GetChildren<Mindroute.Lemoon.Generated.ContentType.ServiceItem>(70);
        var filtered = children.Where(x => x.Featured == true);
        var ordered = filtered.OrderBy(x => x.OrderBy);
        Response.Write(ordered.Count());